# Password length detector with AJAX or jQuery

Tags: jquery

Does any one know how to add a password length checker on the registration form which will detect password length as:

- Weak
- Average
- Good
- Strong

Comment: I dont think length is the be all and end all of what makes a password good.

Comment: allen213 is right; telling someone they have a strong password just because it has a certain number of characters in it is doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of plugins I think could help you.

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/07/jquery-plugin-to-show-password-strength.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple google check: Typed exactely what you needed:

http://gazpo.com/2012/04/password-strength/

Maybe it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

We can integrate lot of Jquery Plugins

For Example: please refer this http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/best-jquery-password-strength-plugin.html

Maybe it'll help you